Vertical alignment changes after removing \frame
I have been developing some typesetting using \frame, after discovering that this command outlines the boxes that LaTeX implicitly uses to arrange the components on each page. However, I have encountered some unexpected changes in alignment when removing the frame command. Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\parbox[b]{15pt}{\centering%
\frame{\parbox{5pt}{a}}~\frame{\parbox{5pt}{b c d}}
}
\parbox[b]{15pt}{\centering%
\parbox{5pt}{a}~\parbox{5pt}{b c d}
}
\end{document}

It produces the following output:

Of course I did not expect that removing \frame would change the layout. I tried replacing \frame with \mbox, assuming that \frame was enclosing its contents in a box that affected typesetting, but this yielded the same change in alignment. I also tried exchanging the tilde ~ for a space, but that made no difference to the respective outputs.
What is happening here, and how can I recover the alignment I get with \frame (which in particular respects the vertical alignment selected for the outer \parbox)?

The baseline of a \parbox is the vertical centre (or at least as understood by \vcenter) unless you use \parbox[t] or \parbox[b]  which is why the unframed parbox aligns such that its vertical centre is on the baseline of the a. However \frame constructs an hbox with two vertical rules between which is a \vbox that has two horizontal rules, between which is an hbox with the supplied content. As such its "natural" referebce point would be the baseline of the final item in the vertical list which would be the bottom edge of the bottom rule of the frame, however latex inserts a negative skip of the rule width so the reference point is always the top edge of the final rule which in simple cases like this correspnds to the baseline of the final line of the content.
It's actually quite hard to add lines in classic tex without affecting spacing.  It's easier in luatex as you can iterate over the nodes after TeX has laid them out, you can see this if you add lua-visual-debug package and run your example with luatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\begin{document}
\parbox[b]{15pt}{\centering%
\frame{\parbox{5pt}{a}}~\frame{\parbox{5pt}{b c d}}
}
\parbox[b]{15pt}{\centering%
\parbox{5pt}{a}~\parbox{5pt}{b c d}
}
\end{document}


So in my MWE it's enough to make each internal \parbox into \parbox[b] (I have tested that this works). I now understand that the first optional parameter of \parbox determines the external alignment, not the internal alignment. I have a further related question, but it seems sensible to put it elsewhere. Thanks!

@MorganRogers no if you use \parbox[b] everywhere you still lose the alignment, replace d by g as the last line and you will see the unboxed one aligns on the baseline of g below the bowl but the framed one aligns on the bottom of the descender

It so happens that for my particular application that result is desirable, but it's important to know for future reference.
